# R - transpose and calculate differences between an unknown amount of date columns. A more readable way possible?

Tags: r, data.table, transpose, sqldf

I'm fitting an unknown amount of multiple date periods within a main sequence of periods. Is there a more readable or more compact way to do it, than my way? I mix sqldf and data.table here since I use both librarys in the project but could do it in pure data.table if needed. Or vice versa. Other well developed libraries are also ok.

No hardcoding, I'm running this with several options and don't know the maximum amount of periods within periods. The amount of within periods don't have a theoretical upper(well maybe 365) limit but a basic sanity check should put the maximum around 6-15 periods, depending on specification.

This is a representation of the working code I use atm (written as a function in the original script).

I would like to belive there should be a shorter/more readable function. Is there anything we can do in the dcast-part that calculates the differences and apply a sum function? I've tried but the fun.aggregate seems limited to more simpler operations.

```
library("data.table")
library("sqldf")

Data <- data.table(
  Fnr      = c(22516, 22516, 22516, 45459, 45459),
  Vernr    = c(1,1,1,1,2),
  Startdat = c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2012-01-01", 
               "2013-04-01", "2013-04-01"),
  Endat    = c("2010-12-31", "2010-12-31", "2012-05-19", 
               "2014-03-31", "2014-03-31"),
  Fromdat  = c("2010-02-21", "2010-08-16", NA, "2013-08-31", "2014-01-02"),
  Tomdat   = c("2010-05-16", "2010-09-11", NA, "2013-10-27", "2014-02-13")
)

tmp.eval <- "list(Fnr, Vernr, Startdat, Endat)"

dt_tmp <- Data[, nobs_id := order(Fromdat), 
               by = eval(parse(text = tmp.eval))]

dt_tmp <- dt_tmp[, c("Fromdat", "Tomdat") := list(as.Date(Fromdat), 
                                                  as.Date(Tomdat))]

dt_tmp <- dcast(dt_tmp, Fnr + Vernr + ... ~ nobs_id,
                value.var = c("Fromdat", "Tomdat"))

dt.colnames <- data.table(colnames(dt_tmp))
dt.col1 <- dt.colnames[substr(V1,1,3) == "Fro"][, c("nobs_id", "Fromdat") := 
                                                list(order(V1),V1)]
dt.col2 <- dt.colnames[substr(V1,1,3) == "Tom"][, c("nobs_id", "Tomdat") := 
                                                list(order(V1),V1)]
dt.set <- merge(dt.col1[,V1 := NULL], dt.col2[,V1 := NULL],
                by = "nobs_id")
dt.set <- dt.set[, diff_col := paste(Tomdat,Fromdat, sep = "-")]
dt.set <- dt.set[, diff_col := paste(diff_col, " diff_",nobs_id, sep = "")]
dt.set <- dt.set[, diffvar_col := paste("as.numeric(diff_",nobs_id,")",
                                        sep = "")]

str.diff <- paste(dt.set$diff_col, collapse = ",")
str.diffvar <- paste(dt.set$diffvar_col, collapse = ",") 
str.diffvar <- paste("sum(", str.diffvar, ", na.rm = TRUE)")

dt_tmp <- sqldf(sprintf("SELECT *, %s FROM dt_tmp",
                         str.diff)
                )

dt_tmp <- setDT(dt_tmp)[Startdat <= Endat, 
                        corr_days := eval(parse (text = str.diffvar)),       
                        by = list(Fnr, Vernr, Startdat, Endat)]
```

Comment: For such a long question it may be hard to get a straight answer here. Fits more into code review. 1. I would not `dcast` but process by group as data as already well modelled (*tidy* using recently popularized term). Then you don't need as many column names substitution with variables/strings, as you keep the data in more generic structure. 2. Not sure why you use `sqldf` here just for a simple single transformation. 3. I would avoid `eval(parse(` on text in favour of `eval(` on language objects, this is nice R feature.

Comment: @jangorecki thx for the tip, I'll be sure to think about that in the future. Sqldf is an artifact, I was going all sqldf first (I thought) and didn't change it  later since I planned to re-write the function anyways. About the eval part, thx, I'm still pretty new to heavy use of R!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do but here's a way to get the same final output of `dt_tmp`.  Assuming I'm interpreting what you're trying to do correctly then the trick is to do your calculations first, then melt that, and then cast it.

```
Data[, nobs_id := order(Fromdat), 
     by = list(Fnr, Vernr, Startdat, Endat)]
Data[,Tomdat:=as.IDate(Tomdat)]
Data[,Fromdat:=as.IDate(Fromdat)]
Data[,diff:=as.integer(Tomdat-Fromdat)]
Data[,corr_days:=sum(diff),by= list(Fnr, Vernr, Startdat, Endat)]
mytemp<-dcast(melt(Data,id.vars=c('Fnr','Vernr','Startdat','Endat','nobs_id','corr_days')),Fnr+Vernr+Startdat+Endat+corr_days~variable+nobs_id,value.var='value')

#if you want them in the same order as your dt_tmp
setcolorder(mytemp, c(names(mytemp)[!names(mytemp)%in%'corr_days'],'corr_days'))



#if you want the date columns to be type character again
datecols<-names(mytemp)[grepl('dat',names(mytemp))]
mytemp[,(datecols):=lapply(.SD,as.character),.SDcols=datecols]
```

Comment: Ok, one other minor thing. I'd fix the dates up front and consider using `as.IDate`. No real reason to keep them as strings and have to format on the fly (e.g., in computing `diff`)

Comment: @Frank yeah, I did it that way because it seemed there might be some reason (although I have no idea what it might be) for it to be kept as a character or else OP would have included the as.IDate (or as.Date) when they assign `Data`.  Obviously your way is better.  I guess I'll change it to that and OP can change back to character if they want.

Comment: Great @DeanMacGregor - this is much shorter! And nicer, I think I was way to set on one path. Realised that I missed one (albeit minor) thing in my question. I have about  30 columns in my real data table with different categorical values. They are fixed so I can name them, but if I don't, it would be a bonus. But the answer is good and much easier to read so I'll happily accept it! (The character dates were only a result of my question, they are dates from the start in the real dt. IDate was a new for me, though)